# Timeline frames shows a lot of "rasterize"

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I hooked up the slow lg android phone with the desktop's google chrome 33 beta to find out why is it working slow for one particular feature on the page that includes waiting until the image is loaded (via imagesLoaded plugin).

To my surprize, there is a lot of long running "rasterize" events and they happen in parallel with the rest of the events (like js and rendering). What is it and why they take so long?

Here is the exported timeline data: https://gist.github.com/thehappycoder/a089562b13e028766e82/raw/53f0425c5f4756c7f5c7662711c4e4d3c6d3ba56/TimelineRawData-20140130T152139.json

And when I don't use imagesLoaded it works like this:
https://gist.github.com/thehappycoder/dc3023a78dbcd486d33d/raw/4b07a650895bdea12ffbc27d60d68f33a7e78c45/TimelineRawData-20140130T153800.json

The code is very simple:

```
$("#divWithImage img").imagesLoaded(function() {
  // No-op
});
```

The demo works fine http://imagesloaded.desandro.com on the phone so it's not about the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spin.js is causing these 'rasterize' events. https://github.com/fgnass/spin.js/issues/200